# Executing c++ code with PHP gives return value of 126

Tags: php, c++, openshift

I have a simple c++ code I want to execute using php on my website hosted by openshift.  The return value it gives me is "126" which means it finds the executable but has a permission issue with running it.  I have the permissions set so it can be executed by all users (0755) so I really can't figure out what the problem is.  I have spent all day searching through stackexchange and other sites and no one has a solution to how to fix this.

The closest I got was with this page "http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/11402-exec-doesnt-work-c-c-executables" which the only solution that worked for him was to finally restart the web server.  Please help!

Comment: ... Did you turn it off and back on again?

Comment: Did you compile the c++ code on OpenShift or at least on a compatible system? (Maybe centos 64 bit or something like that?)